# CSjark: NameError name 'Platform' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm usually not working with Python (but have ability to read the code).
I'm trying to use [csjark](http://csjark.readthedocs.io/).
All the dependencies were installed correctly.
When executing `csjark.py` I'm receiving following error:

```
NameError name 'Platform' is not defined
```

The import is done with `from platform import Platform`

All the *.py files are located in the same folder.
I don't have any issue similar statements for other imports.

Importing with `import platform` is working, but latter I can't use any parameter from the class.

Please suggest ways to resolve the issue with the [`platform.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eventh/kpro9/master/CSjark/csjark/platform.py) file.

Comment: More than likely it is picking-up the standard library module `platform` instead of the csjark version.  Get the folder name that the csjark files are in and add it to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` before you run the program.  How you do that depends on your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your program is importing the wrong platform.py, for example this one:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html
which doesn't seem to have a Platform class. Try renaming the platform.py to something else and importing from that to see if this is the issue.

Comment: i.e platform1.py?

Comment: Yes, something like that